# Crop black padding and resize back to original 1920x1080

Tags: ffmpeg

I have video of resolution 1920x1080 (16:9 aspect ratio). When played its padded with black box on all sides. How to remove the black boxes to get the 1920x1080 video?

[Screenshot of video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HPLi.jpg)

Below the audio and video details:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Maths Logic.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.19.102
  Duration: 00:43:11.24, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1475 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1405 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Comment: Does the video have padding? An image would be helpful: `ffmpeg -ss 60 -i "Maths Logic.mp4" -frames:v 1 output.jpg` Or is it your player adding the padding to fit your screen when using fullscreen playback? What was wrong with the [answer provided in your crosspost?](https://superuser.com/a/1553699/)

Comment: Yes. it has padding

Comment: See [Remove .mp4 video top and bottom black bars using ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/810524/)

Comment: HI, I have gone through the above link, its useful, as applying its cropped the black bars, but the output file shows the video, with the view portion are sliced on the all four sides,

Comment: HI, I have attached the input snap shot.

Comment: HI, you can view the image (attached) which has a padded black bars.along all sides. i want to remove those padded bars to view in 16:9 aspect ratio (without losing the footage area along the sides)

Answer (score 2):

Use [cropdetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#cropdetect) filter to get crop values:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf cropdetect -frames:v 3 -f null -
...
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x559116cfe440] x1:240 x2:1679 y1:56 y2:1078 w:1440 h:1008 x:240 y:64 pts:2 t:2.000000 crop=1440:1008:240:64
```

Then use [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) filter to crop the black, [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) to upscale back to 1080, and then [pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) to fill in missing area to make 16:9 aspect ratio:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "crop=1440:1008:240:64,scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Before and after:

[image: original]
[image: crop and pad]